# mono-test-install reveals I have a broken System.Drawing

Tags: mono, system.drawing

I've gotten the tarball of Mono 3.0.3 from the mono project and compiled it on an Ubuntu 12.10 distro.

The configure, make and make install commands all ran without errors. I ran the mono-test-install and it reports "Your system has a broken System.Drawing setup". I'm not quite sure how to fix this or why it's broken. I have a valid libgdiplus.so file and pointed the configuration options to it.

It seems that I am unable to use the System.Drawing until I get this solved. Has anyone run into this before?

Answer (score 4):

The way the mono-test-install script is testing the System.Drawing setup is to compile the code

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;

class X { 
    static void Main ()
    {
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap (100, 100);
    }
}
```

using the command

```
mcs -pkg:dotnet <filename>
```

and then runs the resulting file with

```
mono <filename>.exe
```

You can do this process by hand to see the actual error message that caused mono to conclude that System.Drawing was broken, possibly allowing you to fix the problem.

Comment: Just some additional info that might help another - mono-test-install runs the code @Benno and produces a warning :

Comment: warning cs0219 the variable b is assigned but its value never used.