# System.Drawing mono failure debugging

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, mono

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18625323/1668057) regarding failed `mono-test-install` results, I put the following in `test.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;

class X { 
    static void Main ()
    {
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap (100, 100);
    }
}
```

Then ran

```
mcs -pkg:dotnet test.cs
```

output:

> test.cs(7,16): warning CS0219: The variable `b' is assigned but its
>   value is never used Compilation succeeded - 1 warning(s)

And ran the resulting exe with:

```
mono test.exe
```

output:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Drawing.GDIPlus ---> System.DllNotFoundException: /usr/local/lib/libgdiplus.so
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Drawing.GDIPlus:GdiplusStartup (ulong&,System.Drawing.GdiplusStartupInput&,System.Drawing.GdiplusStartupOutput&)
  at System.Drawing.GDIPlus..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor (Int32 width, Int32 height, PixelFormat format) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor (Int32 width, Int32 height) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Drawing.Bitmap:.ctor (int,int)
  at X.Main () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Drawing.GDIPlus ---> System.DllNotFoundException: /usr/local/lib/libgdiplus.so
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Drawing.GDIPlus:GdiplusStartup (ulong&,System.Drawing.GdiplusStartupInput&,System.Drawing.GdiplusStartupOutput&)
  at System.Drawing.GDIPlus..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor (Int32 width, Int32 height, PixelFormat format) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor (Int32 width, Int32 height) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Drawing.Bitmap:.ctor (int,int)
  at X.Main () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Is it safe to ignore this or should I be debugging the line `NotFoundException: /usr/local/lib/libgdiplus.so` next?

Comment: See http://www.mono-project.com/DllNotFoundException

Comment: @Jon Skeet Had you read that post or is your Google (wait.. Bing?) Fu just that strong? ;)

Comment: @dwerner: It's the first hit for a search for "DllNotFoundException libgdiplus.so" - really not tricky...

Comment: @JonSkeet - no, it's not tricky, I'm just cheering you on. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks Jon, I'd just found that page and though I didn't follow it verbatim, I put a symlink in as:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libgdiplus.so /usr/local/lib/libgdiplus.so
```

Which resolved the errors and now `mono-test-install` returns:

> Your have a working System.Drawing setup

Besides the grammatical issues, it should be resolved.